# Php Mysql command won't execute

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I can't for the life of me understand how to do this.  I am trying to get the $vo object's info into my $requete and then execute it, but i keep getting the **Catchable fatal error: Object of class Vo could not be converted to string**

Here's the code:

```
<?php

class Dao{

function __construct(){


}


function createOrder($vo){

$server="localhost";
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db   = 'test';

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);

$name=$vo->name;

$requete=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO ha(name, address, city, country, phone, selection) VALUES ($vo->name, $vo->address, $vo->city, $vo->country, $vo->$phone, $vo->selection)";
$db->exec($requete)or die ("failure");
echo "success";


}
}

?>
```

Comment: where is $vo coming from?

Comment: vo is an object, its from here:

<?php

class Vo{


public $name;
public $address;
public $city;
public $country;
public $phone;
public $selection;


function __construct($name, $address, $city, $country, $phone, $selection){

$this->name=$name;
$this->address=$address;
$this->city=$city;
$this->country=$country;
$this->phone=$phone;
$this->selection=$selection;

}


}


?>

Comment: Try  '$vo->city' or even   $var= $vo->city      then pass $var to the query

Answer (score 0):

Try the string below:

```
$requete = $db-prepare("insert into ha (name,address,city,country,phone,selection) values ('$vo->name', '$vo->address', '$vo->city', '$vo->country', '$vo->$phone', '$vo->selection')");
```

You need to quote the values. To understand why...
Lets say the name of a user is:

George Johnson, Jr.

Can you see why you need to quote this? It is because if there is a comma that is part of the name, the SQL statement would be misinterpreted.

Wrong:

> value (George Johnson, Jr. , 123 Elm Street)

Right:

> value ('George Johnson, Jr.', '123 Elm Street')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$requete=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO ha(`name`, `address`, `city`, `country`, `phone`, `selection`) VALUES ($vo->name, $vo->address, $vo->city, $vo->country, $vo->$phone, $vo->selection)";
$db->exec($requete)or die ("failure");
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code and use question marks as your place holders for your prepared variables. and you have a syntax error in your prepared statement, you cannot use prepared statement and use your pdo to execute the prepared statement `$db->exec` should be `$requete->execute`

```
$name=$vo->name;
$address=$vo->address;
$city=$vo->city;
$country=$vo->country;
$phone=$vo->phone;
$selection = $vo->selection;

$requete =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `ha`(`name`, `address`, `city`, `country`, `phone`, `selection`) VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
try {
 $requete->execute(array($name, $address, $city, $country, $phone, $selection));
} catch (Exception $ex) {
 echo $ex->getMessage();
 die();
}
```